# Rowspan Not Working with my css where i have used display:table

Tags: html, css

I Have a table with has fixed header i.e it has scrollbar on tbody, but the rowspan property is not working.
I have used bootstrap 4 for table classes and also used flex

css :-

```
#jobs-table tbody {
    display: block;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 356px);
    text-align: center;
    overflow-y: scroll;

}
#jobs-table tr {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
#jobs-table thead {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #4A90E2;
}
#jobs-table table {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    width: 100%;
}
#jobs-table thead tr{
  width: calc(100% - 15px);
}
```

Html :-

```
    <div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table table-stripped" id="jobs-table">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Level No</th>
            <th>Question Id</th>
            <th>Answer</th>
            <th>Score</th>
            <th>Time Taken</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td rowspan="4">level</td>
            <td>5b28864e2eddc223ef5643fe</td>
            <td>CORRECT</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>20</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>5b2884962eddc223ef564186</td>
            <td>CORRECT</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>20</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>5b2886232eddc223ef564376</td>
            <td>CORRECT</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>20</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>5b28864e2eddc223ef56439c</td>
            <td>CORRECT</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>20</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td rowspan="5">level</td>
            <td>5b28867b2eddc223ef564478</td>
            <td>CORRECT</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>20</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>5b2885db2eddc223ef564369</td>
            <td>CORRECT</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>20</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>5b28867b2eddc223ef56445f</td>
            <td>WRONG</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>20</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>5b28867b2eddc223ef564464</td>
            <td>CORRECT</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>20</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>5b28864e2eddc223ef5643b5</td>
            <td>CORRECT</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>20</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

I cant figure it out why the rowspan is not working and if there is some way to achieve my desired output?

My Expected output is something like this :-
[image: Ignoring the borders]

Comment: It's worth noting that you have 5 columns in your `thead` and only 4 in your `tbody`

Answer (score 0):

Your display properties appear to be causing the issue. I have removed both and got the desired effect you were after, see below the revised CSS:

```
#jobs-table tbody {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 356px);
    text-align: center;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
#jobs-table tr {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
#jobs-table thead {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #4A90E2;
}
#jobs-table table {
    width: 100%;
}
#jobs-table thead tr{
  width: calc(100% - 15px);
}
```

Comment: If i remove the display properties the header is not fixed,as i have mentioned that the table body should be scrollable